# Intrinsic optimization of SM4 encryption using AVX2

Tags: encryption, optimization, intrinsics

The performance of SM4-cbc encryption is influenced by the feedback dependency. I was wondering how to improve the encryption speed by using AVX2 instrinsics or any other methods?

Below is the C code snippet of my implementation, of which the performance should be improved by 3x.

```
// rk, Arr* are all of uint32_t.

uint32_t T(uint32_t a1, uint32_t a2, uint32_t a3, uint32_t rk)
{
    ka = a1 ^ a2 ^ a3 ^ rk;
    uint32_t ka1 = (unsigned char)(ka),                                                                         
        ka2 = (unsigned char)(ka>>8),                                                                      
        ka3 = (unsigned char)(ka>>16),                                                                     
        ka4 = (unsigned char)(ka>>24);     

    return Arr1[ka1] ^ Arr2[ka2] ^ Arr3[ka3] ^ Arr4[ka4];
}

uint32_t one_round(uint32_t input[4])
{
    uint32_t a0, a1, a2, a3;
    a0 = input[0];
    a1 = input[1];
    a2 = input[2];
    a3 = input[3];

    // This block will repeat many times using different rk
    a0 ^= T(a1, a2, a3, rk[0]);
    a1 ^= T(a2, a3, a0, rk[1]);
    a2 ^= T(a3, a0, a1, rk[2]);
    a3 ^= T(a0, a1, a2, rk[3]);

}
```

Comment: Does it have to run fast on Haswell / Ryzen, or can you assume fast gather instructions (Skylake, and to a lesser extent Broadwell) for the Arr[] lookup tables?  If I'm reading this right, there's a data-dependent table lookup where the address depends on the data being encrypted.

Comment: Can you interleave 2 or 4 data streams in parallel in your use-case? i.e. after loading 4x4=16 bytes from 2 different inputs streams into the lower / upper halves of a single `__m256i`, you run SH4 on each 128-bit lane independently, so all your shuffles are in-lane and you don't have to work around serial dependencies within one stream to take advantage of 256b vectors.